# Dynamic iframe inside click event for any attribute like input, select, textarea and button click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('iframe').on('load', function () {
    var ifr = $(this).contents();
    $(ifr).on("click", 'input, select, text, a, button', function () {
        var _thisDoc = this;
        console.log(_thisDoc);
    });
});
```

Dynamic iframe inside click event for any attribute like input, select, textarea and button click event not working

Comment: Is there any error on the console? Some iframes are not fetchable outside due to CORS issues.

Comment: We can't know what error you are experimenting, or at least, what behaviour you are having and what was the expected behaviour.

Comment: @cooskun I am not get any errors

Comment: @madtyn I am trying to do for iframe inside input clicking after add input tag dynamically

Comment: Then add that intention to your question and also add why that is not happening. Details help others to give you advice. Also describe deeply how the current behaviour differs from expected behaviour